USB connection for Doro cell phone detected by lsusb but not by Disks application (Ubuntu 24.04)
On my Windows 11 PC I installed Ubuntu 24.04. I have an old-fashioned cell phone
(no internet connection), with an USB cable for connection to computers :

When I'm in the Windows 11 OS and I connect the phone through the cable, the connection is correctly and immediately detected :

When I'm on the Ubuntu OS however, the phone is nearly not detected at all, not even in the Disks application (even though my phone screen says "USB Connected" when I plug in the cable), so I cannot even format it. I say "nearly" because the lsusb command detects it :
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0489:e0e2 Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0e8d:0002 MediaTek Inc. phone (mass storage mode) [Doro Primo 413] <- THAT'S MY PHONE.
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 3277:0033 Shinetech USB2.0 FHD UVC WebCam
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub


I tried sudo modprobe usb-storage as suggested in an older answer here but it changed nothing.
On the other hand, USB connection of just about anything else (USB key, external hard drive etc) works fine on my Ubuntu.
Any ideas on what is going on here and how to fix this ?

When you connect the phone under Windows, is it detected as an USB drive (mass storage device)? In such case, it gets its own drive letter (like for example F:) and is visible in Windows Explorer exactly like eg. an USB stick. Or is it connected in some other way and Explorer displays something else in the location bar than a drive letter?

@raj Thx for your feedback. I've just realized I had forgotten to include some images in my question, this is fixed now. I think those images answer the questions in your comment

Seems like your phone is visible like a regular USB drive. In that case I don't understand why it doesn't work under Linux. I see two options: 1) the phone memory has a filesystem that is understood by Windows, but not understood by Linux. The only thing that comes to mind is exFAT. Does the lsblk command show any new disk when you plug in your phone?


Some phones can connect to a PC in two modes: charging only or mass storage. I have such a phone and when I plug it in it asks me (on the phone display) which mode I want to choose. If I don't choose "mass storage", the computer won't see anything (but it's the same for both Windows and Linux). Maybe your phone is similar, but somehow autodetects the mode and this autodetection is based on some Windows behavior which Linux does not exhibit. In this case, you're probably out of luck unless you find a way to manually force your phone to connect in mass storage mode.


@raj Answer to question about lsblk command : its output does not change when I plug in the disk. If you look at the line detecting my phone in the lsusb command, which is Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0e8d:0002 MediaTek Inc. phone (mass storage mode) [Doro Primo 413], it looks like storage mode is chosen indeed. Which makes it all the more mysterious why it's not detected outside of lsusb

If it connects in mass storage mode - as the message says - I really don't know why it isn't visible as a disk (even if unformatted or with unrecognized format). Sorry, I can't help more.

@raj Don't be sorry, you've already allowed me to improve my question a lot ...

when you connect your phone (that has android OS) it isn't mounted in /mnt or /media directory in root file system (other usb devices are mounted in /media directory as you know and you can access them there).
that's why when you use fdisk command or other similar commands you can not see your phone.
the android OS use media transfer protocol (MTP) to communicate with your Linux machine. but you have to be able to access your phone via file manager but if you can't, you should use gvfs-mtp or jmtpfs packages to access you phone in command line.
check this manual to understand more about these command
https://www.baeldung.com/linux/mounting-mtp-devices

The OP says he has an "old-fashioned cell phone", so it's probably not a smartphone, ie. no Android. Such phones often used AT commands-based protocol to communicate with PC, emulating a serial connection over USB. It is possible that it's the case.

@raj Yes, you are absolutely right, my phone is not a smartphone at all, the OS is definitely not android.

The instructions in the link don't work on my Ubuntu 24.04 OS. When I try sudo apt install gvs-mtp I get the error message E: Unable to locate package gvs-mtp
